# Pagination problem with multiple loops on the same page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, loop, customization

I'm using 4 custom loops to display 3 posts on each one and every loop has its own pagination which works fine once the page loads up, the problem is that when I click on the 2nd page of the first loop it does show me the next 3 posts of that loop but it does the same for the other 3 loops, so if one of these loops has only 2 posts it won't show any if I click on the 2nd page of any of the other.

Is there a way to page the pagination aware of what the loop is and only scroll through that loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Meh, I ended up doing it with AJAX which was the thing I was trying to avoid, hopefully someone knows another way to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might wanna try wp_reset_query(); at the end of your loops

Comment: I did but since the page parameter gets pulled from the URL it does nothing